# Received a completed event for test with unknown id... Registered test ids...?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit5, kotlintest

I created a brand new project in Android Studio. Here is the software information:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 26, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.5.2
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 16
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: ru.leoklo.stackuml, com.intellij.marketplace, com.alibabacloud.intellij.toolkit-intellij, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.jetbrains.kmm, com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI, org.intellij.plugins.markdown
```

Below are the contents of the app's **build.gradle** file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kotlintestexample"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage', 'RtlHardcoded', 'VectorPath'
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 2
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            returnDefaultValues = true
        }
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.4.2'
    testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk:1.10.6'
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.5.0"
    testImplementation  "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.1"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.1"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.1"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

This is the unit tests that I have written:

```
package com.example.kotlintestexample

import io.kotlintest.specs.BehaviorSpec
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue

class GradeCalculatorSpec : BehaviorSpec({

    Given("a grade calculator") {
        When("obtained marks are 90 or above") {
            Then("grade is A") {
                assertTrue(true)
            }
        }
        When("obtained marks are between 80 and 89") {
            Then("grade is B") {
                assertTrue(true)
            }
        }
        When("obtained marks are between 70 and 79") {
            Then("grade is C") {
                assertTrue(true)
            }
        }
        When("obtained marks are between 60 and 69") {
            Then("grade is D") {
                assertTrue(true)
            }
        }
        When("obtained marks are below 60") {
            Then("grade is F") {
                assertTrue(true)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

As you can see, this is very simple. However, this is the error that I received when I tried to execute these tests:

```
~~~ Project Configuration ~~~
-> Parallelism: 1 thread
-> Test order: LexicographicSpecExecutionOrder
-> Soft assertations: False
-> Write spec failure file: False
-> Fail on ignored tests: False
-> Extensions
  - io.kotlintest.extensions.SystemPropertyTagExtension
  - io.kotlintest.extensions.RuntimeTagExtension
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.5'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.5'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.6'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.6'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.7'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.7'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.8'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.8'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.9'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.9'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.10'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.10'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.11'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.11'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.12'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.12'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.13'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.13'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor431.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.InterruptibleRunnable.run(InterruptibleRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> Received a completed event for test with unknown id '17.4'. Registered test ids: '[:app:testDebugUnitTest, 17.1, 17.2]'
```

I tried to follow the advice provided [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6453) to no prevail.

Does anyone have any other bright ideas in order to troubleshoot and possibly resolve this? Or should I report this to JUnit / Gradle?